# get a excluded day in a the month

Tags: mongodb, date

I want to get all the data from the month in mongodb

lets say i want to get all the data from September, except 23 Sep
i think of 
createdAt 1 sep AND createdAt not in 23,24 sep
but it only execute the  createdAt not in 23,24 sep

is there other ways?

```
db.getCollection('myTest').find({
    "$and":[{    
      createdAt:{ "$gte": ISODate("2019-09-01T16:00:00.000Z")},
        createdAt:{ "$nin": [ISODate("2019-09-23T16:00:00.000Z"),    ISODate("2019-09-24T16:00:00.000Z")]}
  }]
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.test.aggregate([{$project:{date:"$date",month:{$month:"$date"},year:{$year:"$date"}}},{$match:{$and:[{date:{$nin:[ISODate("
2019-09-23T00:00:00Z")]}},{month:9},{year:2019}]}},{$project:{_id:1,date:"$date"}}])
])
```

1. To get the month number $month,$year operator gives month and year number
2. $nin for not in date and check month and year number to get particular month in a year
3. $project the required values
   [image]